# Oracle - Multiple Rows from Multiple Tables Into One Field

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a query that can take multiple fields from multiple tables and merge them into one field. Ex. I have a query that looks like:

```
select to_char(a.comments), to_char(b.comments), to_char(c.comments)
from      crm.custprob a
left join crm.custcall b on b.servno = a.servno
left join crm.custlog c on c.servno = b.servno
where a.servno = 1716942
```

and produces the output:

```
a.comments   b.comments    c.comments
1 Regular    3 Primary     5 Log
1 Regular    3 Primary     4 Log
1 Regular    2 Other       5 Log
1 Regular    2 Other       4 Log
```

What I would like is a query that would produce the output all in one line, and in one field (I don't care about the order of the numbers) so it would look like:

```
Comments
1 Regular 2 Other 3 Primary 4 Log 5 Log
```

Comment: use the `||`  opoerator (replace comma's with || in your select) or nest `concat`'s since the function only supports 2 strings, you'd have to nest a concat.

Comment: Replacing the commas still returns 4 rows though, I'd like it down to 1 row if possible

Comment: ahh then you need `wm_concat()` or `ListAgg()` depending on the version of oracle you're using.

Answer (score 1):

First get a list of all comments. You'd use `UNION` for this, not joins. Then use `LISTAGG` to aggregate rows and concatenate the comments:

```
select listagg(comments, ' ') within group (order by comments) as comments
from
(
  select to_char(comments) as comments from crm.custprob where servno = 1716942
  union
  select to_char(comments) as comments from crm.custcall where servno = 1716942
  union
  select to_char(comments) as comments from crm.custlog where servno = 1716942
);
```

(And in case there can be no duplicates, you'd use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`).

(Updated according to below comments where it shows that `comments` is of type `NCLOB`.)

Comment: Depending on version of Oracle, LISTAGG (11g) may not be available. Consider use of undocumented feature WM_CONCAT()  instead if LISTAGG not supported.

Comment: This looks close, but it's throwing the error  'ORA000904: "COMMENTS": invalid identifier" referring to the comments in the "within group (order by comments)". I tried replacing it with 'crm.custprob.comments' mbut it still errors out

Comment: Strange. Maybe using the same name as an alias causes the problem. Can you try replacing `as comments` with `as comment_list`, please?

Comment: or possibly alias the subquery "B" and put B. in listagg and comments. (before comments word)

Comment: Still the same error, it's identifying the 'order by comments' as the problem, though comments is definitely a valid column. It does the same thing if I try to order it by servno too

Comment: Here was the problem, the lines in the union needed to have aliases too, ex: select to_char(comments) as comments from crm.custprob where servno = 1716942
  union

Comment: `to_char(comments)`? Where does that come from? It's not in my query.

Comment: Thanks everyone, xQbert and Thorsten Kettner!

Comment: comments is NCLOB, so to_char was to make it a string

Comment: Okay, right, then the result of `to_char(comments)` needs a name. I simply didn't expect `comments` not to be varchar2 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that does the listagg on the individual tables before joining:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID, '1 regular' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, '1 abnormal' comments FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 1 ID, '2 other' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 ID, '3 primary' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, '2 something else' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, '3 secondary' comments FROM dual),
     t3 AS (SELECT 1 ID, '4 log' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 ID, '5 log' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, '4 log' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, '5 log' comments FROM dual)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.comments||' '||t_2.comments||' '||t_3.comments comments
FROM   t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID, listagg(comments, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY comments) comments
                        FROM   t2
                        GROUP BY ID) t_2 ON t1.id = t_2.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID, listagg(comments, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY comments) comments
                        FROM   t3
                        GROUP BY ID) t_3 ON t_2.id = t_3.id;

        ID COMMENTS
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 1 regular 2 other 3 primary 4 log 5 log
         2 1 abnormal 2 something else 3 secondary 4 log 5 log
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select listagg(comments, ' ') within group (order by ordering) as comments
from (select comments from crm.custprob, 1 as ordering where servno = 1716942
      union all
      select comments from crm.custcall, 2 where servno = 1716942
      union all
      select comments from crm.custlog, 3 where servno = 1716942
     ) x;
```